# Reverse each character in a string except special characters (e.g. "?")

Tags: c++

For example : how are you? ----> woh era uoy?

This is my code, i got it worked but the question mark is besing reversed too.
How can i make it remained intact?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string ch;
    while(cin >> ch)
    {
         for(int i = ch.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
         {
             cout << ch[i];
         }
         cout << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if punctuation exists in the middle of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your chosen input method (`cin >> ch`) automatically splits the input into separate words.
Like [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin) said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19603189/15168), you have to skip over punctuation etc to find to alpha characters to swap.  Roughly like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string ch;
    while (cout << "String? " && cin >> ch)
    {
        cout << "Input:  <<" << ch << ">>\n";
        const char *bp = ch.c_str();
        const char *ep = ch.c_str() + ch.length() - 1;
        const char *sp = ch.c_str();
        while (sp < ep)
        {
            while (sp < ep && (*sp != ' ' && !isalpha(*sp)))
                sp++;
            while (sp < ep && (*ep != ' ' && !isalpha(*ep)))
                ep--;

            char c = *sp;
            ch[sp-bp] = *ep;
            ch[ep-bp] = c;
            sp++;
            ep--;
        }
        cout << "Output: <<" << ch << ">>\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample dialogue

```
String? How are you?
Input:  <<How>>
Output: <<woH>>
String? Input:  <<are>>
Output: <<era>>
String? Input:  <<you?>>
Output: <<uoy?>>
String? Pug!natious=punctuation.
Input:  <<Pug!natious=punctuation.>>
Output: <<noi!tautcnu=psuoitanguP.>>
String?
```

You can tweak it from here.  I'm far from claiming this is idiomatic C++; the use of `const char *` in the middle shows my C background.

Answer (score 1):

Start from the beginning of the string, and scan forward until you find a letter. The scan backwards from the end until you find a letter. Swap them. Continue until the two positions meet.

Note: above I've used "letter", but all I really mean is "one of the characters that should be reversed." You haven't defined very precisely which characters should be swapped and which shouldn't, but I'm assuming you (or your teacher) has a reasonably specific definition in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try using array and scanning each letter to see if there is a question mark. If there is, move it to the last place of the array.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution or hack to solve this case alone. if there are more cases comment it lets solve it together.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string ch;
    while(cin >> ch)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        for(int i = ch.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
                if(ch[i] != '?')
                        cout << ch[i];
                else
                        flag = 1;
        }
        if(flag)
                cout << "?";
        else
                cout << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```